# Debugging regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that should work on strings:

```
2[23 3] + [1 22 3] + 7
[2] + [12351]
12[45 12]
[56]
[2] + 1 + [2]
```

but it also should throw an exception on strings:

```
2[2 a]
1[2 3 4] + []
3[2 3 4] + a[1 2 3] 
3[2 3 4] +
```

and I wrote the following RegEx and code which throws an exception with information about an error position:

```
String sVariables = "(\\[(\\d+)(\\s+\\d+)*\\])";
String sMonomial = "((\\d+" + sVariables + "?)|" + sVariables + ")";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sMonomial + "(\\s+\\+\\s+" + sMonomial + ")");
Matcher m = p.matcher(sPolynomial);
if (m.find() && m.end() != sPolynomial.length()) 
    throw new FileParseException(sPolynomial, m.end(), lineNumber);
else if (!m.find())
throw new FileParseException(sPolynomial, 1, lineNumber);
```

But I have no idea why it doesn't work and it is very hard to find a mistake. So the question is how to find a mistake in RegEx? How to test it properly? Is there any programs which will generate output for my RegEx to find out how it works?

**Update:** I think I should write more about the nature of this strings. The RegEx should describe all strings which represent special kind of polynomials in special format. The format is

1. Polynomial is a list of monomials separated with +. (e.g. `m1 + m2 + m3`)
2. Monomial is a number, or list of numbers in square brackets separated with spaces, or it can contain both number and list of numbers. (e.g. `2[1 2 3]`, `2`, `[2 3 4]`)
3. All other strings should be rejected

Comment: Try [Debuggex](http://debuggex.com) or [Explain Regex](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=) to get a good feel for what your regular expression should be doing.

Comment: What are the rules for rejection of those sets?

Comment: @RohitJain well, there is only one rule for rejection "if it doesn't match the pattern than it should be rejected". The pattern in more common language is `digit\[list of digits\] (\+ digit\[list of digits\])*`. And all other strings should be rejected.

Comment: @DaZzz - In that case, your current code is trivially correct ... but your common language translation of the pattern is probably incorrect :-)

Comment: @StephenC yes, it is a little bit simplified. But I've updated my question. So now it should be more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this regex:

```
^((\\d+)?\\[[ \\d]+\\]|\\d+)(\\s*\\+\\s*(\\d+)?\\[[ \\d]+\\]|\\s*\\+\\s*\\d+)*$
```

It can be broken down to a first group:

```
(\\d+)?\\[[ \\d]+\\]
```

To match `x[y z]` stuff (where x, y and z are numbers).

```
\\d+
```

To match the numbers without any `[x y]` with them.

```
(\\s*\\+\\s*(\\d+)?\\[[ \\d]+\\]|\\s*\\+\\s*\\d+)*
```

This matches `+ x[y z]` or `+ x` 0 or more times.

See [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/vG0aC3) for an example.

In your code, it would be probably:

```
String sVariables = "(\\d+)?\\[[ \\d]+\\]";
String sMonomial = "(" + sVariables + "|\\d+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^" + sMonomial + "(\\s+\\+\\s+" + sMonomial + ")*$");
```

EDIT: Misplaced the caret and quote.

Comment: @DaZzz thanks for pointing out the misplaced quote ^^; I would have accepted it should I have been reviewing edits. Sorry that it got rejected by other members of the community :(

Comment: it's ok. Not your fault. :)